# Did I use RowFilter on DataView with Threading correctly?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dataview

EDIT: I am using VS2008, .NET 3.5

I have a DataTable, which is populated in a DataView and passed into a CollectionView.

```
   DataTable newLeadTable = new DataTable();
   myConnection.Open();
   dbAdpater.Fill(newLeadTable);
   this.LeadDataView = new DataView(newLeadTable);
   this.LeadsCollectionView = 
   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeadDataView);
```

Then the DataGrid that use to display the data is binding to `this.LeadsCollectionView`

After the user enter the filter text in the View, the ViewModel will execute this method to set the filter string on the DataView:

```
private void SetLeadListFilter(string LeadFilterStr)
{
  this.LeadDataView.RowFilter = filterString;
}
```

It works fine, I can see the DataGrid shows proper filtered DataRow.

But then I want to give some UI Experience, add a busy indicator.
So I put the above code into a Thread:

```
this.IsBusy = true;
Thread filterDataThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{        
    this.LeadDataView.RowFilter = filterString;
    this.IsBusy = false;
}));
filterDataThread.Start();
```

Now is strange, I can see the code was ran, filter being setted.  But the DataGrid doesn't filter out the rows!

So now I modify the method, reassign the DataView into the CollectionView again:

```
this.IsBusy = true;
Thread filterDataThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{        
    this.LeadDataView.RowFilter = filterString;
    this.LeadsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeadDataView); //Added this
    this.IsBusy = false;
}));
filterDataThread.Start();
```

Now it working! The data is being filter properly on the DataGrid!

So why is this happen when I use threading? Is this the proper way to use DataFilter in Threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say for sure, but, as I've understand, you use

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeadDataView);
```

to get the Datasource for your DataGrid. Answer is based on this assumption.
So if you will cal this method outside the `filterDataThread`, like this:

```
this.IsBusy = true;
Thread filterDataThread= new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{        
    this.LeadDataView.RowFilter = filterString;
    this.IsBusy = false;
}));
filterDataThread.Start();
this.LeadsCollectionView =  
  CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeadDataView);
```

then the code with `GetDefaultView` will probably run **before** your Thread work - there would be a race between `MainThread` and `filterDataThread`, and `MainThread` wins, and your `DataGrid` doesn't filter the data.

But if you will use the code you've provided:

```
this.IsBusy = true;
Thread filterDataThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{        
    this.LeadDataView.RowFilter = filterString;
    this.LeadsCollectionView =  
      CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LeadDataView); //Added this
    this.IsBusy = false;
}));
filterDataThread.Start();
```

the filtering will start in right time.
So answer is:
Yes, you are doing the filtering right. But you should add code to handle errors while performing operations in background thread so your application wouldn't be `Busy` forever.

Also, you should check the safe access to the `filterString` - if you'll start two or more threads for filtering, there would be another race with unpredictable results.